# Determine the possible grouping

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider I have a set of $3$ object $1,2 $ and $ 3.$ What is the possible grouping? I'll have either $\{(1,2,3)\}$  or $\{(1),(2),(3)\}$ or $\{(1,2),(3)\}$ or $\{1,(2,3)\}$ or $\{(2,(1,3)\}.$ So, I'll have $5$ possible grouping. In the same manner for $4$ objects, I'll have $14$ possible grouping.
So, What about $n$ numbers and how could I formulate it?

Comment: You are looking for Bell Numbers. Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number Also for $4$ it will be $15$ not $14$.

Comment: Thanks for useful hint, Andres; yes, It is the solution. Just wondering whether there is a code or pseudo-code for partitions or not